# Is it case study or narrative research? We are using interviews and diary studies

Tags: research-process, methodology

How do I know if my study uses the case study approach or narrative research approach?
What factors do I have to take into account to differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a qualitative research methodology. You should take a class on qualitative research methods to learn a systematic approach to what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to read up on methodology and methods.

- approach
- strategy
- methods

You may want to look up Saunders et al. (2019): I think they are on 8th edition. (I'm not sure if they have a new one).

Inbtw, you may have narrative or phenomenological analysis within case study and as stand alone without case study.